# mod_wsgi supported input characters

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

Currently my group has a Django server set up on Ubuntu 8, using Apache, Django, Python and mod_python. We are planning to set up a new server to replace this one. The new server will be running updated versions of the software the current server is running. 
For example, Ubuntu 12 will be used, Django will be updated from 1.3 to 1.5, and Python will be updated to 2.6 or 2.7
One thing that will change is that instead of mod_python, we will be using mod_wsgi. This is largely due to the fact that as of version 1.5, Django has removed mod_python support, instead using mod_wsgi (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/internals/deprecation/#id2).
The problem is that we are using the ARK naming scheme, and have had problems with the ARK syntax and mod_wsgi in the past. Here is some info about ARK:

*An ARK is a special kind of URL that connects users to
   three things: the named object, its metadata, and the provider's
   promise about its persistence.  When entered into the location field
   of a Web browser, the ARK leads the user to the named object.  That
   same ARK, inflected by appending a single question mark (`?'),
   returns a brief metadata record that is both human- and machine-
   readable.  When the ARK is inflected by appending dual question marks
   (`??'), the returned metadata contains a commitment statement from
   the current provider.*

Here is the ARK specification page, where the info above came from: (https://wiki.ucop.edu/download/attachments/16744455/arkspec.txt?version=1&modificationDate=1261036800000)

In the past, mod_wsgi was not accepting the trailing **?** or **??** characters, which are integral to the ARK specification. I have searched for hours and can't seem to determine if support has been added for these characters in mod_wsgi, or if some workaround will need to be implemented.

Please let me know if you know about this, or if you need any other information from me. 
Thanks in advance,
John

Answer (score 0):

Answered on mod_wsgi mailing list at:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/modwsgi/T0nanTIUL_4